ADB "error: protocol fault (couldn't read status message): No error" when pairing over wifi
I'm trying to connect my Android device via Wifi to adb by using the 6 digit pairing code.
On my Android device phone I enabled wireless debugging and clicked on "Pair device with pairing code". In the Windows 10 PowerShell I try to connect by running adb pair <IP>:<port>, this is the output (it loads for some time after entering the code):
adb pair 192.169.0.99:46351
Enter pairing code: 393041
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status message): No error

I'm running Android SDK Platform-Tools 35.0.2
When connecting via QR code in VS code, there's no problem, so I don't think it's a network issue.
I already tried:

reconnecting phone and PC to the Wifi
Restarting the adb process with adb kill-server and adb start-server
Updating all Android SDK tools
Making sure the adb port 5037 is not occupied by a different process
running netsh interface portproxy reset


What device model is your Android device and what Android version is running on it?

@Robert Samsung Galaxy A34 5G running Android 14

May be logcat log from Android device contains an error message that explains a bit what is going wrong. Therefore I would recommend to first connect the device via USB adb to the computer, start adb logcat and then start the adb WiFi pairing process.
